# what if a package has relative requires?

Tags: javascript, requirejs, package

I managed to get some form of [Off-The-Record](https://github.com/arlolra/otr) in the async format that requirejs likes, but the code has relative requires in it like `require("../vendor/bigint.js")`. That *should* work fine, since the main file is `lib/otr.js` so `vendor` is just another directory in the package. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong...

```
...
packages: [
  { name: "OTR", 
    location: "deps/betterotr", 
    main: "lib/otr" 
  },
  ...
]
```

and in my module that uses otr, it calls

```
define(["OTR"],(OTR) => {...})
```

So, what I'd expect is that `require("../vendor/bigint.js")` would request the file within the OTR package, at the location of the OTR package. Instead what I see my browser doing is...

1. request `file://my/app/deps/betterotr//lib/otr.js`
2. request `file://my/app/OTR/vendor/bigint.js`
3. fail

So... no idea what to do about that. `require("../vendor/bigint.js")` is treating the package name as if it were the package's location, and not looking up the package's location to resolve the path. Do I just have to always have my package name equal to my package's location? It's nice to keep that stuff in `deps`...

The folder structure is:

- deps/betterotr/lib/otr.js
- deps/betterotr/vendor/bigint.js
- js/otruser.js
- js/main.js
- other stuff

where main.js has `require.config({})` in it.

Comment: what is your folder and file structure? which files contain what requires ?

Comment: I'll add the folder structure, thanks.